# Django Rest : How to get back a base64 encoded string instead of link to the image from my serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I currently have something like this

```
class Serializer_ListEmployee(ModelSerializer):
    user = Serializer_ListUser()
    class Meta:
        model = modelEmployee
        fields = [
            'user',
            'employee_image',
        ]
```

Any suggestions on how I can get back a base64 encoded string instead ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want the get the base64 from serializer then you can do something like this : [Edit as mentioned in another answer]

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    employee_image = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
class Meta:
        model = modelEmployee
        fields = [
            'user',
            'employee_zip',
            'employee_image',
        ]
    def get_employee_image(self, place):
        img = open( self.employee_image.path, "rb") 
        data = img.read() 
        return "data:image/jpg;base64,%s" % data.encode('base64')
```

Reference : http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield

But if you want two way, like read and write both then you can go with something like this :

```
from django.db import models  
class Photo( models.Model ):  
    title = models.CharField( max_length=255 ) 
    image = models.ImageField( upload_to="photos/", max_length=255) 
    @property 
    def image_url( self ):
        try:
            img = open( self.image.path, "rb") 
            data = img.read() 
            return "data:image/jpg;base64,%s" % data.encode('base64') 

        except IOError:
            return self.image.url
```

Source : http://www.codedependant.net/2012/04/13/increase-site-performance-with-django-base64-encod/

Answer (score 1):

Create a serializer method for image field. In that field read the image from source and convert it base64 string.

Refer here http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield for creating a method field.